# How to detect black object on black background using Python OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to detect a black tape on a black background.

I have first cropped the area of the tape from the original image and then performing thresholding on it. Below is the image when there is no tape:

[image]

You can notice there is an almost solid line. Black tape is placed right next to it and when it is placed this line becomes very light. Below is the image:

[image]

Is there any good image processing techniques I can use to detect when the black tape is placed and when its not placed?

Below is the code I am currently using:

```
import cv2
import os
import imutils
from pathlib import Path
import numpy as np

def on_mouse(event, x, y, flags, param):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        print("X: {} | Y: {}".format(x, y))

dirPath = Path(__file__).parents[2]
imgPath = os.path.join(dirPath, "img", "img.png")
win_name = "Image"
cv2.namedWindow(win_name)
cv2.setMouseCallback(win_name, on_mouse)

img = cv2.imread(imgPath)
img = imutils.resize(img, width=800)
roiImg = img[298:337, 520:591]

img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(roiImg, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
rett, thresh = cv2.threshold(img_gray, 50, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

cv2.imshow(win_name, img)
cv2.imshow("Thres", thresh)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Here is the link to test video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Pio3Xkx_SuHidDs1UdacS3-DZqA-CiXQOX/view?usp=sharing

Below is the image with area marked in red where tape is usually placed

[image]

Comment: you show pictures in which A LOT is going on. please focus on the area that matters to you. -- is this going to be some kind of automated optical inspection? if so, that workplace and camera isn't set up for it.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz  I have added image showing area where tape is usually placed. Because its a black on black detection, its difficult to explain via images thats why I have added video as well. I am not sure about optical inspection but will search about it

Comment: that object moves... alignment (here, ECC refinement is probably good), then pixelwise differences. that part of the picture is tiny. move the camera a lot closer. and see if you can prevent things from moving around. in general, optical inspection requires that things always be in the exact same place too.

Comment: Are you still looking for a solution?

Comment: @AnnZen Yes but as a temporary solution I am using a hand detection model. So once the hand detection model detect hands in the roi of black tape, I am considering it as done.

Comment: Since the images in this question have been deleted, the question now needs a [mcve], and can be put on hold.

Answer (score 0):

No way to write a stable image processing software here.

In this industrial environment you get differences in ambient light, reflexion, shadows, light different presentation angles, sun light etc. This will impact the brightness of your image partial or global much more than the presence of a nearly invisible tape. This way it's not possible to find any good threshold.

So I guess you are on the right way using the "temporary solution" of detecting the gray hand.
If you really like to detect the tape you need a hardware solution that brings you away from this black on black thing:

1. Use white tape on black part or black tape on white part. Only to mention :-)
2. [Use dark/bright field illumination](https://www.stemmer-imaging.com/en/knowledge-base/bright-field-illumination/) instead of ambient light. Guess will not work because angle of part and tape is similar.
3. Use different wavelength with more difference than in visible light. Needs [specific camera](https://www.visco-tech.com/english/product/devices/nircamera/) and illumination. Best wavelength depends a lot of the material but that's the most professional and stable solution here.